# remove css style on button click jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change the colour of buttons if they're clicked using jquery.

my code bellow works and it will add the expand class to the clicked button. but I need to know how I can remove the class and add the old class to it if another button is clicked and visa versa.

this is my code now:

```
$(".mybtn").click(function(){
  $(this).removeClass( "mybtn" ).addClass('expand');

});
```

and the html is like this:

```
<button name='mybtn' id='mybtn' class='mybtn' value='1'>1</button>
<button name='mybtn' id='mybtn' class='mybtn' value='2'>2</button>
<button name='mybtn' id='mybtn' class='mybtn' value='3'>3</button>
```

and the css is a simple css with background color:

```
.mybtn{
background-color:#fff;
}

.expand{
background-color:#000;
}
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: FYI IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve a toggle effect on click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset all the "expand" class objects first:

```
$(".mybtn").click(function(){
   // remove expand class and add original mybtn class
  $(".expand").removeClass( "expand").addClass("mybtn");

  $(this).removeClass( "mybtn" ).addClass('expand');

});
```

See working example at [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6yjFw/)

Comment: this is exactly what I needed to do. Thank you Jim.

Comment: FYI: You can get the same results [without ever removing the "mybtn" class](http://jsfiddle.net/6yjFw/1/)

Comment: @user3806613, please mark this one as the right answer if it worked for you :)

Comment: @entiendoNull, I did try to do that but STO says I have to wait for 5 minutes before accepting the answer. it is now 2 minutes. so will accept it as soon as the time limit is up.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.mybtn').toggle(function () {
    $(".mybtn").removeClass("mybtn").addClass("expand");
}, function () {
    $(".mybtn").removeClass("expand").addClass("mybtn");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$(".mybtn").each(function(){    
   $(this).click(function(el, ev){
      $('button#mybtn').addClass('mybtn').removeClass('expand'); 
      $(this).removeClass( "mybtn" ).addClass('expand');     
   }); 
})
```